# print prepared statements with fmdb

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

Is there any way to print the prepared statements, or at least implement the sqlite3_trace function when using fmdb? trying to access the statement from the FMResultset didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sqlite3_trace` function

```
void myTraceFunc(void *uData, const char *statement)
{
    NSLog(@"%s", statement);
}
```

can be implemented with

```
FMDatabase *db = ...;
[db open];
sqlite3_trace([db sqliteHandle], myTraceFunc, NULL);
```